# List Items from props not displaying upon reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I have stumbled upon a problem I can not seem to figure out. My component "Event Selector" is supposed to create a button for each item in 'lists' passed to it from props. However upon reload, and/or re-opening the website the list items do not display. Confusingly, they do display when any source file is modified and saved. What could be causing this, and how do you propose I solve it?

A side note, I am pulling this information from a Google Firestore database upon loading/reloading the page, and the array although appearing different in the console output when un-expanded, to my novice eye looks like it contains the same information.

I would also love any other tips which you may have. I have just started with JS, React, and MaterialUI.

My "Event Selector" component:

```
class EventSelector extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render() {

        const { classes, lists } = this.props;

        console.log(lists)
        return (

            <div>
                <Grid container item 
                        direction='column' 
                        alignItems='center' 
                        justify='center' 
                        style={{ maxHeight: '70vh', maxWidth: '50vw' }} 
                        spacing={5}>

                        <Grid item>
                            <h1 className={classes.h1}>Upcoming Events</h1>
                            <h2 className={classes.h2}>Please select an event to sign up</h2>
                        </Grid>

                    <Grid container item direction='row' justify='center' spacing={5}>

                        <List component='b' subheader={<ListSubheader componenet='b'>Upcomming Events</ListSubheader>}>
                            {lists.map(( {key , id} ) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={id}>
                                        <ListItem button>
                                            <ListItemText inset primary={key}/>
                                        </ListItem>
                                    </div>
                                );
                            }) }

                        </List>

                    </Grid>   

                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
```

This is my page function

```
export default function PageDisplay(props){

    const classes = useStyles();

    // let page = <EventSelector lists={events()}/>
    var page = props.page

    if (props.page == 1) {page = <EventSelector lists={props.lists}/>}
    else if (props.page == 2) {page = <NameInformation/>}
    else if (props.page == 3) {page = <EmailAcademic/>}
    else if (props.page == 4) {page = <GeneralQuestion/>}

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid item container
                direction='column'
                alignItems='center'
                justify='center'
                style={{ minHeight: '50vh' }}>

                    <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper}>
                        {page}
                    </Paper>

            </Grid>
        </div>
        
    );
}
```

This is my Forum componenet

```
class Fourm extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = { // answers and page state

            offered: this.getAvailableEvents(),
            selected: {},

            page: 1,
            pages: 4,


            first: "",
            last: "",
            pronouns: "",

            email: "",
            year: "",
            program: "",

            q1: "",
            q2: "",
            q3: "",
        }

        // this.state.offered = 

        this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);

    }

    getAvailableEvents = () => {

        var lst = [] // this is a list of events s.t. {key: "event_name"}

        const eventsRef = db
                        .collection('events'); // this is a reference to the events collection

        const offeredRef = eventsRef
                        .where('allowRegistration', '==', true)
                        .get() // this contains all docs which allow registration.
                        .then((querySnapshot) => {
                            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { // for each document, create key value pairs
                                lst.push({key: doc.data().name, id: doc.id})
                            })
                        })
        // console.log(lst)
        return ( lst );
    }

    nextPage = () => {
        this.updateState({page: this.state.page + 1})
        console.log(this.state.page)
    }

    render = () => {

        // console.log(this.state.offered)

        return(

            <div>
                <Grid item>

                    <Grid item container 
                            spacing={3} 
                            direction='column'
                            alignItems='center'>


                        <Grid item>
                            <PageDisplay page={this.state.page} lists={this.state.offered}/>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item>
                            <Navigation></Navigation>
                        </Grid>

                    </Grid> 

                </Grid>
                

                
            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default Fourm;
```

Here are screenshots of the issue:

**Issue**
[before modifying and saving code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQGHF.png)

**What is should look like**
[after modifying and saving code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoHFi.png)

**After reloading page**
[after reloading page without modifying code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVEGA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change how you're setting `this.state.offered`.

Where you first define `offered:` within this.state in your Forum class, this can just be some dummy example data or an empty array / string (whatever the data type is) rather than the actual function like you are currently doing.

What you then need to do, is update the `offered` state in your getAvailableEvents function (where you are currently doing a return at the end of the function).

Finally, you will want to use the componentDidMount method or similar in your forum class, and stick getAvailableEvents within that. This means, that whenever the page is shown or rendered, it will call your function, get the data and update state (and in turn update the component and what is rendered on screen).

React docs - `componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.`